# SQLFreeHandle Segfault in SnowFlake access thru ODBC Driver on Unix

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc, rsa, unixodbc

I have created a C++ App on Unix which connects Snowflake thru Snowflake ODBC driver.
Sometime (Not always) - My App gets `segmentation fault`. I am providing stacktrace below.
As I use `Private Key` from Vault which rotates every time. Also, this below error does not comes always - it looks to me it is related to parsing `Private Key`. Do I need to pass some configuration in ODBC.ini and pass dsn connection string in some specific format **?**

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x00007fff50aa98c1 in _Latin1FromUnicodeWithOffsets () from [Location of SnowFLake Driver]
> (gdb) bt
> #0  0x00007fff50aa98c1 in _Latin1FromUnicodeWithOffsets ()
> from [Location of SnowFLake Driver]
> #1  0x00007fff50aa0390 in _fromUnicodeWithCallback () from [Location of SnowFLake Driver]
> #2  0x00007fff50aa06aa in ucnv_fromUnicode_58__sb64 () from [Location of SnowFLake Driver]
> #3  0x00007fff50ae8f92 in sbicu_58__sb64::UnicodeString::doExtract(int, int, char*, int, UConverter*, UErrorCode&) const () from [Location of SnowFLake Driver]
> #4  0x00007fff50ae92b7 in sbicu_58__sb64::UnicodeString::extract(int, int, char*, unsigned int, char const*) const () from [Location of SnowFLake Driver]
> #5  0x00007fff5064c764 in Simba::Support::simba_wstring::GetAsAnsiString (
> this=0x7fff53db0510 Simba::Support::SimbaSettingReader::s_instance+112,
> in_encoding=Simba::Support::ENC_US_ASCII) at PlatformAbstraction/simba_wstring.cpp:779
> #6  0x00007fff5081e543 in GetAsPlatformString (
> this=0x7fff53db0510 Simba::Support::SimbaSettingReader::s_instance+112)
> at ../../Include/Support/simba_wstring.h:406
> #7  Simba::Support::SimbaSettingReader::Internal_ReadSetting (
> this=0x7fff53db04a0 Simba::Support::SimbaSettingReader::s_instance, in_valueName="ANSIENCODING")
> at PlatformAbstraction/SimbaSettingReader_Unix.cpp:653
> #8  0x00007fff5081ec5b in Simba::Support::SimbaSettingReader::ReadSetting (in_valueName="ANSIENCODING")
> at PlatformAbstraction/SimbaSettingReader_Unix.cpp:566
> #9  0x00007fff5082115a in Simba::Support::SimbaSettingReader::GetAppCharEncoding ()
> at PlatformAbstraction/SimbaSettingReader_Unix.cpp:248
> #10 0x00007fff50592d13 in Simba::DSI::DSIDriver::SetDefaultPropertyValues (this=0xd64ca0)
> at DSIDriver.cpp:341
> #11 0x00007fff50592fe9 in Simba::DSI::DSIDriver::DSIDriver (this=0xd64ca0) at DSIDriver.cpp:202
> #12 0x00007fff50b766d9 in Simba::Snowflake::SFDriver::SFDriver() ()
> from [Location of SnowFLake Driver]
> #13 0x00007fff50b4b73a in Simba::DSI::DSIDriverFactory(unsigned long long&) ()
> from [Location of SnowFLake Driver]
> #14 0x00007fff505b80d8 in Simba::DSI::SharedSingletonManager::Initialize (in_isServer=)
> at SharedSingletonManager.cpp:159
> #15 0x00007fff508f8e40 in Simba::ODBC::Driver::InitializeSingletons (this=0x1db5030)
> at Driver/Driver.cpp:585
> #16 0x00007fff508f9deb in Simba::ODBC::Driver::Initialize (this=0x1db5030) at Driver/Driver.cpp:438
> #17 0x00007fff508fac97 in Simba::ODBC::Driver::Driver (this=0x1db5030) at Driver/Driver.cpp:406
> #18 0x00007fff5087c39d in Simba::ODBC::Driver::GetDriver () at ./Driver/Driver.h:250
> #19 0x00007fff508668ff in SQLAllocHandle (HandleType=1, InputHandle=0x0, OutputHandle=0x7fffffff79f8)
> at CInterface/CInterface.cpp:807
> #20 0x00007fffefc82e29 in ?? () from //datadirect/7/lib/libodbc.so
> #21 0x00007fffefc948e0 in ?? () from //datadirect/7/lib/libodbc.so
> #22 0x00007fffefc59f88 in **SQLFreeHandle** () from /opt/datadirect/7/lib/libodbc.so
> #24 0x00007fffda02dce9 in __run_exit_handlers () from /lib64/libc.so.6
> #25 0x00007fffda02dd37 in exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
> #26 0x00007fffda01655c in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
> #27 0x000000000047a329 in _start ()